# Protect file's creation date from being modified in iOS

Tags: ios, file, terminal, file-permissions

I am trying to protect the Creation and last modification dates from a file in iOS so other users don't change them by using the `SetFile` or `touch` commands on the terminal.

Is it even possible to do this on iOS?